# Read a file in chunks in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to read a file in MB chunks, is there a cleaner way to do this in Ruby:

```
FILENAME="d:\\tmp\\file.bin"
MEGABYTE = 1024*1024
size = File.size(FILENAME)
open(FILENAME, "rb") do |io| 
  read = 0
  while read < size
    left = (size - read)
    cur = left < MEGABYTE ? left : MEGABYTE
    data = io.read(cur)
    read += data.size
    puts "READ #{cur} bytes" #yield data
  end
end
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Adapted from the Ruby Cookbook page 204:

```
FILENAME = "d:\\tmp\\file.bin"
MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024

class File
  def each_chunk(chunk_size = MEGABYTE)
    yield read(chunk_size) until eof?
  end
end

open(FILENAME, "rb") do |f|
  f.each_chunk { |chunk| puts chunk }
end
```

Disclaimer: I'm a ruby newbie and haven't tested this.

Comment: Yes, this works. However, I thought that IO.read would throw if the number of bytes left was less than chunk size. I thought that because I had read about IO.readbyte, which will throw TruncatedDataError. Looks like that does NOT apply to read. An oversite on my part.
Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively, if you don't want to monkeypatch `File`:

```
until my_file.eof?
  do_something_with( my_file.read( bytes ) )
end
```

For example, streaming an uploaded tempfile into a new file:

```
# tempfile is a File instance
File.open( new_file, 'wb' ) do |f|
  # Read in small 65k chunks to limit memory usage
  f.write(tempfile.read(2**16)) until tempfile.eof?
end
```

Comment: Quick Q: Why `2**16`? I see others using `2**20`, `1024` and `1024*1024`. You've got a lot of rep, so thought I would ask you. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `IO#each(sep, limit)`, and set `sep` to `nil` or empty string, for example:

```
chunk_size = 1024
File.open('/path/to/file.txt').each(nil, chunk_size) do |chunk|
  puts chunk
end
```

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks for reminding me, I forgot the sep argument. It should read a file in chunks now.

Comment: `each` with `sep` == `nil` and `sep` == `’’` both returned variable length chunks for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the ruby docs:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html
there's a line that goes like this:

```
IO.foreach("testfile") {|x| print "GOT ", x }
```

The only *caveat* is. Since, this process can read the temp file faster than the 
generated stream, IMO, a latency should be *thrown* in.

```
IO.foreach("/tmp/streamfile") {|line|
  ParseLine.parse(line)
  sleep 0.3 #pause as this process will discontine if it doesn't allow some buffering 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/IO.html#method-i-read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.5/IO.html#method-i-read) gives an example of iterating over fixed length records with `read(`*`length`*`)`:

```rb
# iterate over fixed length records
open("fixed-record-file") do |f|
  while record = f.read(256)
    # ...
  end
end
```

> If *length* is a positive integer, `read` tries to read *length* bytes without any conversion (binary mode). It returns `nil` if an EOF is encountered before anything can be read. Fewer than *length* bytes are returned if an EOF is encountered during the read. In the case of an integer *length*, the resulting string is always in ASCII-8BIT encoding.

Answer (score -1):

```
FILENAME="d:/tmp/file.bin"

class File
  MEGABYTE = 1024*1024

  def each_chunk(chunk_size=MEGABYTE)
    yield self.read(chunk_size) until self.eof?
  end
end

open(FILENAME, "rb") do |f|
  f.each_chunk {|chunk| puts chunk }
end
```

It works, *mbarkhau*. I just moved the constant definition to the File class and added a couple of "self"s for clarity's sake.

Comment: I wouldn't use the extra constant MEGABYTE, instead: `def each_chunk(chunk_size=2**20)`