# Read a file from tar.gz file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, file-io

I am trying to read a specific file from a tar.gz file using following code

```
def get_data_file_file(file, type)
   begin
      Gem::Package::TarReader.new(Zlib::GzipReader.open(file)).each do |entry|
         if(entry.full_name == type)
            return entry.read
         end
      end
   rescue Zlib::GzipFile::Error => e
      stacktrace = e.backtrace.join("\n")
      LOGGER.error("ERROR: #{e.message}\n #{stacktrace}")
      return nil
   end
   return nil
end
```

But problem is coming because of size of the file as "entry.read" read the entire file in one shot and keep in the memory.

Anyone knows about any alternative? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Try to read it chunk by chunk, by giving an argument to read  with the number of bytes you want to read:

```
entry.read(1024*1024) #1mb each time
```

More information here:
[Read a file in chunks in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682120/read-a-file-in-chunks-in-ruby)

Comment: Thanks for response. Yeah i can use the method suggested by you but i am looking whether there is any other library which offer to read a compressed file line by line.