# 'Failed to allocate memory' error with large array

Tags: ruby, arrays, memory-management

I am trying to import a large text file (approximately 2 million rows of numbers at 260MB) into an array, make edits to the array, and then write the results to a new text file, by writing:

```
file_data = File.readlines("massive_file.txt")
file_data = file_data.map!(&:strip)
file_data.each do |s|
    s.gsub!(/,.*\z/, "")
end
File.open("smaller_file.txt", 'w') do |f|
    f.write(file_data.map(&:strip).uniq.join("\n"))
end
```

However, I have received the error `failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)`.  How can I allocate more memory to complete the task?  Or, ideally, is there another method I can use where I can avoid having to re-allocate memory?

Comment: If I were you I'd focus on making this more incremental - there's no need to read the whole file in one go.

Comment: As @FrederickCheung advises, you should be reading the input file one line at a time. You can do that with [IO#foreach](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach): `IO.foreach("input_file") do |line| ... end`. Transform `line` in the block and then append that to the output file.

Comment: You should understand that you are making multiple copies of the data in memory.  On your f.write line "map", "uniq", and "join" will all make full copies of the data, with "uniq" cutting it down perhaps.  Still, 260MB starts to add up when you multiply it.  Take others' advice here and simply process the data incrementally.

Comment: An alternative method, depending on your needs, might be to use a database. SQLite should easily be able to handle this much data without you needing to worry about memory use.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file line by line:

```
require 'set'
require 'digest/md5'
file_data = File.new('massive_file.txt', 'r')
file_output = File.new('smaller_file.txt', 'w')
unique_lines_set = Set.new

while (line = file_data.gets)
    line.strip!
    line.gsub!(/,.*\z/, "")
    # Check if the line is unique
    line_hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(line)
    if not unique_lines_set.include? line_hash
      # It is unique so add its hash to the set
      unique_lines_set.add(line_hash)

      # Write the line in the output file
      file_output.puts(line)
    end
end

file_data.close
file_output.close
```

Comment: Given the size of the files, you should make `unique_lines_array` a set rather than an array. Also consider making the elements of that set hashcodes computed for each line. Note you initialize. `unique_lines_array` as `unique_lines_dictionary`.

Comment: Yes, you are right for everything. Thanks for the note.

Comment: More potential improvements: you probably don't need an MD5 hash, `String#hash` will suffice. Also, did you really mean `while (line=file_data)`? Seems to me you meant to use `while (line=file_data.readline)`, though that will raise an exception when the end of the file is reached. `file_data.each_line do |line|` is probably best. You can also rewrite `line_hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(line); if not unique_lines_set.include? line_hash; unique_lines_set.add(line_hash);` as simply `if unique_lines_set.add? line.hash` Finally, don't forget to close `file_data` and `file_output`.

Comment: You also striped the line twice; that's not necesssary.

Comment: You are right, I've edited the code with the correct file line reading and the file close.

Comment: If I'm not missing something you doesn't insert `\n` between lines in the output file, you probably want to use `puts` in place of `write`.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about not needing md5 - with a 32 bit hash code the probability of collisions across 2 million values is pretty high (if running ruby on a 64 bit platform the odds are better)

Answer (score 0):

You can try reading and writing one line at once:

```
new_file = File.open('smaller_file.txt', 'w')
File.open('massive_file.txt', 'r') do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    new_file.puts line.strip.gsub(/,.*\z/, "")
  end
end
new_file.close
```

The only thing pending is find duplicated lines

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can read file in chunks which should be faster compared to reading it line by line:

```
FILENAME="massive_file.txt"
MEGABYTE = 1024*1024

class File
  def each_chunk(chunk_size=MEGABYTE) # or n*MEGABYTE
    yield read(chunk_size) until eof?
  end
end

filedata = ""
open(FILENAME, "rb") do |f|
  f.each_chunk() {|chunk|
      chunk.gsub!(/,.*\z/, "")
      filedata += chunk
  }
end
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1682400/3035830

Comment: Following this approach makes removing duplicate lines extremely difficult.