# Uploading Large File to S3 with Ruby Fails with Out of Memory Error, How to Read and Upload in Chunks?

Tags: ruby, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

We are uploading various files to S3 via the Ruby AWS SDK (v2) from a Windows machine. We have tested with Ruby 1.9. Our code works fine except when large files are encountered, when an out of memory error is thrown.

At first we were reading the whole file into memory with this code:

```
:body => IO.binread(filepath),
```

Then after Googling we found that there were ways to read the file in chunks with Ruby:

```
:body =>  File.open(filepath, 'rb') { |io| io.read },
```

This code did not resolve the issue though, and we can't find a specific S3 (or related) example which shows how the file can be read and passed to S3 in chunks. The whole file is still loaded into memory and throws an out of memory error with large files.

We know we can split the file into chunks and upload to S3 using the AWS multi part upload, however the preference would be to avoid this if possible (although it's fine if it's the only way).

Our code sample is below. What is the best way to read the file in chunks, avoiding the out of memory errors, and upload to S3?

```
require 'aws-sdk'

filepath = 'c:\path\to\some\large\file.big'
bucket = 's3-bucket-name'
s3key = 'some/s3/key/file.big'
accesskeyid = 'ACCESSKEYID'
accesskey = 'ACCESSKEYHERE'
region = 'aws-region-here'

s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  :access_key_id => accesskeyid,
  :secret_access_key => accesskey,
  :region => region
  )

resp = s3.put_object(
  :bucket => bucket,
  :key => s3key,
  :body =>  File.open(filepath, 'rb') { |io| io.read },
  )
```

Note that we are not hitting the S3 5GB limit, this is happening for files for example of 1.5GB.

Comment: Have you looked at this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682120/read-a-file-in-chunks-in-ruby) it outlines the chunking concept pretty concisely.

Comment: @engineersmnky  Yes it does, however it's not clear how that would be adapted in this case, if it can be - can you show some sample code?

Comment: what version are you using because I am not as familiar with v2 but in v1 `S3Object#write` automatically chunks the upload. Your issue is that you are trying to use `put_object` where as i would create a `S3Object` and then write to it in chunks but version is very important here.

Comment: @engineersmnky we are using SDK v2

Comment: have you tried just `:body => File.open(filepath,'rb')` seems body accepts just an IO which should chunk stream but like I said less familiar with v2 and they made the source difficult to decompose

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The v2 AWS SDK for Ruby, `aws-sdk` gem, supports streaming objects directly over over the network without loading them into memory. Your example requires only a small correction to do this:

```
File.open(filepath, 'rb') do |file|
  resp = s3.put_object(
   :bucket => bucket,
   :key => s3key,
   :body => file
  )
end
```

This works because it allows the SDK to call `#read` on the file object passing in a small number of bytes each time. Calling `#read` on a Ruby IO object, such as a file, without a first argument will read the entire object into memory, returning it as a string. This is what has caused your out-of-memory errors.

That said, the `aws-sdk` gem provides another, more useful interface for uploading files to Amazon S3. This alternative interface automatically:

- Uses multipart APIs for large objects
- Can use multiple threads to upload parts in parallel, improving upload speed
- Computes MD5s of data client-side to for service-side data integrity checks.

A simple example:

```
# notice this uses Resource, not Client
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
  :access_key_id => accesskeyid,
  :secret_access_key => accesskey,
  :region => region
)

s3.bucket(bucket).object(s3key).upload_file(filepath)
```

This is part of the `aws-sdk` resource interfaces. There are quite a few helpful utilities in here. The Client class only provides basic API functionality.

Comment: Trevor, great answer. That's exactly what we were after in part 1, and excellent recommendation on part 2. Question though, with the resource there does not appear to be a field for the MD5 hash like there is in the put_object method. Does it do this automatically when using the resource method?

Comment: When using the v2 `aws-sdk` gem, a MD5 hash is automatically computed on all requests that accept them. This is true for both the client `#put_object` method and the resource `#upload_file` method. I'll add that to my answer above.

Comment: Interesting that the put_object still accepts the MD5 option and the resource upload_file does not - good to know.

Comment: The put_object method accepts an md5 in case the user already knows it, they can save on computation time. The upload_file method switches between put and multipart and has to compute md5s for parts when performing a multipart upload.

Comment: Hey @trevor-rowe we have tested with the second option here and still get an out of memory error ("File too big for single read") - is there another way the Resource method can be used to mitigate this?

Comment: @jotap Can you link to a gist showing how you are using the SDK?

Comment: Yep here is the relevant code @trevor-rowe https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0565098e1d4117395afb

Comment: Also @trevor-rowe I should mention that it works for 1.5GB files but not for say a 3GB file. It also fails immediately when it's invoked, rather than starting to upload then running out of memory.

Comment: @jotap That sound like the entire file is being read into memory, instead of being streaming in chunks. I've commented on your gist, looking for more information.

Comment: Actually it turned out to be an unrelated code error when we were doing an MD5 hash of the file - false alarm! Thanks for the reply @trevor-rowe

Comment: The sdk automatically computes md5 hashes for you. You shouldn't need to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The size limit for a bucket in .put is 5GB.

However there is "multipart" upload in s3 where you can upload the files with large size.

These links might help you:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/MultipartUpload.html

Comment: thanks, it's actually not to do with the 5GB limit, it's hitting a memory limit before that, eg with a 1GB file. Will edit the question to say that. Your links are for the v1 SDK and the code uses the v2 SDK. The question also mentions we know about the multi part upload, however that does not address the question of how to read the file in chunks and pass to the S3 client. If that's the only way then we need that to be the answer, and would need to see some justification for that answer.