# Is there a way to write a file to S3 in Ruby or Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, sidekiq

I am a user of Sidekiq with a use case that requires very heavy logging and file writing. I have some old workers that write directly to the file system. This isn't good because it keeps me from being able to spin up several small utility instances as needed. It has been recommended to me to instead write the files to S3.

Some of these files are pretty large, up to millions of lines in the case of some reports. Is there a way to buffer output to a file on S3?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105178/uploading-large-file-to-s3-with-ruby-fails-with-out-of-memory-error-how-to-read?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 4):

As per the description shared, you will be needing the below mentioned gem for uploading resources to S3

```
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

Below mentioned class shows the method to initialize, store and get the public_url of the resource stored.

```
class S3Store
 TEST = "app-uploads".freeze

 def initialize file
  @file = file
  @s3 = AWS::S3.new
  @bucket = @s3.buckets[TEST]
 end

 def store
  @obj = @bucket.objects[filename].write(@file.tempfile, acl: :public_read)
  self
 end

 def url
  @obj.public_url.to_s
 end

 private

 def filename
  @filename ||= @file.original_filename.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.]/, '_')
 end
end
```

Below mentioned code shows the calling method of above class.

```
image = S3Store.new(File.read(path_to_file)).store
```