# Out of memory issue while using Multipart upload API of AWS s3

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, awss3transfermanager

I am trying to use aws multipart upload using aws SDK and spark and file size is around 14GB but getting out of memory error. Its giving error at this line - `val bytes: Array[Byte] = IOUtils.toByteArray(is)`

I have tried to bump up driver memory and executor memory to 100 G and tried few other spark optimizations.

Below is the code I am trying with :-

```
val tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard.withS3Client(s3Client).build
      val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
      val filePath = new Path(hdfsFilePath)
      val is:InputStream = fs.open(filePath)
      val om = new ObjectMetadata()
      val bytes: Array[Byte] = IOUtils.toByteArray(is)
      om.setContentLength(bytes.length)
      val byteArrayInputStream: ByteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
      val request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, byteArrayInputStream, om).withSSEAwsKeyManagementParams(new SSEAwsKeyManagementParams(kmsKey)).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.BucketOwnerFullControl)
      val upload = tm.upload(request)
```

And this is the Exception I am getting :-

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)
                at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117)
                at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
                at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
                at com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:45)
```

Comment: If the library supports it, it would probably be better to send a stream rather than converting the whole thing to a byte array.  Here is a related question that you can look at to guide you on more things to look for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105178/uploading-large-file-to-s3-with-ruby-fails-with-out-of-memory-error-how-to-read?rq=1

Comment: Hi, you can have a look at [Benji S3 lib](https://zengularity.github.io/benji/s3/usage.html) (I'm a contributor of), which support Akka Streams on object storage ops

Answer (score 0):

`PutObjectRequest` [accepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#PutObjectRequest-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata-) `File`:

```
public PutObjectRequest(String bucketName, String key, File file)
```

Something like the following should work (I haven't checked though):

```scala
val result = TransferManagerBuilder.standard.withS3Client(s3Client)
  .build
  .upload(
    new PutObjectRequest(
      bucketName,
      keyName,
      new File(new Path(hdfsFilePath))
    )
    .withSSEAwsKeyManagementParams(new SSEAwsKeyManagementParams(kmsKey))
    .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.BucketOwnerFullControl)
  )
```